# Is there any upper limit for number of groups used or the length of the regex in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am new to using regex.  I am trying to use the regex find and replace option in Notepad++.

I have used the following regex:

```
((?:)|(\+)|(-))(\d)((?:)|(\+)|(-))(/)((?:)|(\+)|(-))(\d)((?:)|(\+)|(-))
```

For the following text:

```
2/2
+2/+2
-2/-2
2+/2+
2-/2-
```

But I am able to get matches only for the first three.  The last two, it only gives partial matches, excluding the last "+" and the "-".  I am wondering if there is any upper limit for the number of groups (which i doubt is unlikely) that can be used or any upper limit for the maximum length of the regex.  I am not sure why my regex is failing.  Or if there is anything wrong with my regex, please correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue with Notepad++'s regex engine. The problem is that when you have alternations like `(?:)|(\+)|(-)`, the regex engine will attempt to match the different options *in the order they are specified*. Since you specified an empty group first, it will attempt to match an empty string first, only matching the `+` or `-` if it needs to backtrack. This essentially makes the alternation *lazy*—it will never match any character unless it has to.

*vks*'s answer works perfectly well, but just in case you actually needed those capturing groups separated out, you can do the same thing just by rewriting your alternations like this:

```
((\+)|(-)|(?:))(\d)((\+)|(-)|(?:))(/)((\+)|(-)|(?:))(\d)((\+)|(-)|(?:))
```

or even more simply, like this:

```
((\+)|(-)|)(\d)((\+)|(-)|)(/)((\+)|(-)|)(\d)((\+)|(-)|)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
([-+]?)(\d)([-+]?)(/)([-+]?)(\d)([-+]?)
```

You can use this simple regex to match all cases.See here.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/19

Comment: It was my mistake not mentioning that I need the groups separated out since I am doing conditional replace.  But your regex works for the matching part.